# Is there a way to one-time open Firefox bypassing the home pages?

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to bypass the home pages set in Firefox when opening the application?

I have multiple home pages set on Firefox which I use very often.  Many times throughout the day I would like to open Firefox and not have it open any of the home pages.  Is there a way to do this?  If I remember correctly, way back in the days, IE or Netscape allowed you to hold down the shift key while opening the app and it would not open your home page.  I am looking for similar functionality, does it exist?

Answer (score 9):

You can create a shortcut that opens firefox with a different webpage.

Set a shortcut to

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe" about:blank
```

or whatever your firefox path is.

The easiest way to do this would be to copy an existing shortcut and add 'about:blank' (or any webpage) to the end of the `Target`.

Comment: Beat me to it ;)

Comment: Beat me to it as well.   Upvotes for both of you!

Comment: My special keylogger echos your computer's keyboard to mine. It delay's your enter key by about a half second though.

Comment: Not nice, but I guess it will work

Answer (score 3):

You could start Firefox with `about:blank` for the URL. Just create a shortcut to FF with this for the location:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "about:blank"
```

Linux would be done similarly:

```
firefox "about:blank"
```